# Is there a way to link two SharePoint lists together?

Tags: 2013, links-list

I currently have two lists (list A and list B).
If a user enters a record into list A, I want it to populate the same record into list B...

Is that possible?

Many of the columns are the same in both Lists, but the columns that are not in both list just wouldn't populate in the second list (List B).

Any suggestions or information would be grateful.

Thank you!

Comment: Sorry you question is confusing. The columns that are not common will not get populated unless you provide the mapping.

Comment: Ok that is fine, I only want the columns that are in common to populate... will the column names have to be identical to populate?

Answer (score 2):

Do the following:

Site actions -> Site Settings -> Site Columns

From there click "Create"

You can now decide what type of column to create. In this case, click "Lookup (information already on this site". Further down, under the option "Get Information From" select the list you wish to pull the info. From there you can select the main piece of information and the subsequent related information you wish to display.

Once you create this column, go to the list in which you want to insert the column, click "List Setting" then "Add existing column". I save my custom columns in the group "Custom Columns". Click the newly created column, and insert it into your list. It will populate with the different pieces of information you're pulling.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I TRIED YOUR STEPS AND it seems like when I added a record to list A it didn't appear in B.... Does the column names have to be exactly the same when adding them?

Answer (score 0):

You can create an event receiver or a workflow, and provide the mapping for are the column values you need.

Below is the link you can see how to create an event receiver and workflows.

Event Reciver - http://seminda.wordpress.com/2011/09/08/creating-sharepoint-2010-event-receivers-in-visual-studio-2010/

Workflows - http://blogs.salmanghani.info/copy-item-workflow-using-sharepoint-designer-2010/