# Connect two sharepoint lists

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, custom-list

I do not know programing, but I can use SharePoint for my requirements. I want to connect two SharePoint lists in to one. Lookup column is not enough to meet my requirement, is there any way to link two lists ?

Comment: Can you explain why a Lookup is not enough?

Comment: If a lookup field is not enough you can try to get information from one list via Microsoft Flow to the other list (SP list create/update trigger)

Answer (score 0):

Look up column connection is a straight way to implement this but as you said lookup column didn't work for you, not clear on this why didn't work.

**Similar question already has been discussed here:**

[Is there a way to link two SharePoint lists together?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/127972/is-there-a-way-to-link-two-sharepoint-lists-together)

**Follow this link to do some work around - same implementation is done here:**

https://www.nhaustralia.com.au/blog/link-two-lists-microsoft-sharepoint/

**If you are ok to buy some third party tool to implement this, you can go with the boostsolutions integration, just plug and play** :-)

http://www.boostsolutions.com/blog/how-to-integrate-multiple-sharepoint-lists-into-one-list/

Comment: I created two lists for two groups which have different permission levels 01 Group - Contribute without edit & Delete 02, Group - Contribute without delete, both groups use same ID for their works & I want to show comments updated by group 02 to group 01 - hence I want to update the list which is used by group 01 automatically (Like Excel) based on 2nd list which is used by Group 02

Answer (score 0):

To merge two lists in SharePoint Online, you can create Linked data source in SharePoint Designer.

Refer to the following article about how to link two lists and create a combined view in SharePoint 2013 (Which is also works in SharePoint online):

https://www.ignatiuz.com/blog/sharepoint-2013/how-to-link-two-lists-and-create-a-combined-view-in-sharepoint-2013/